# Create a dynamic table in excel by selecting data from another table when a certain condition is satisfied

Tags: excel, office365

In a certain sheet of Excel I've placed these datas (let's call such a table "Table 1"):

[image]

where:

- ID may be 0 or 1 and it indicates if the number in the same row and in the column "value" must be ignored or not in the following.
- Value is the data I need to use in the following

Now, in a different sheet, I need to create a dynamic table ("Table 2") with the same number of rows of the rows of Table 1 with ID = 1. And I have to put the values of such rows in table 1. Ideally, Table 2 should update and change its size if some IDs of Table 1 are switched from 0 to 1 and viceversa.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

Insert table on your data then in cell F2 (for example) use the below (Office 365):

> =FILTER(Table1,Table1[ID]=1)

[image]

Comment: I realized that the formula i posted earlier is not 100% correct.

i made a small change as :
 =FILTER(Table1,Table1[ID]=1)